# issue related to cmake and openmp

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, openmp

I am trying to compile a program on QT creator with cmake. The code(its not my code, I am using it to test something) uses openMP. in my cmake file I have:

```
`enter code here`project(dbscan_try) 
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8) 
 aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "{CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -Wall -fPIC -pedantic -fopenmp -mtune=corei7-avx")

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF) set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON) set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF) add_definitions(-DBOOST_UBLAS_NDEBUG) add_definitions("-std=c++11") add_definitions("-fopenmp")

add_definitions("-lgomp")

OPTION (USE_OpenMP "Use OpenMP" ON) 
find_package(OpenMP) 
if (OPENMP_FOUND) 
  message("OPENMP FOUND") 
  set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}") 
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}") 
  # set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}") 
endif() 

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -fopenmp")

find_package(PCL REQUIRED COMPONENTS) include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS} ) link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS}) add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

include_directories({/home/raman/Work/dbscan_try}) 
set(project_SOURCES
   /home/raman/Work/cplusplus_projects/dbscan_try/main.cpp
   /home/raman/Work/cplusplus_projects/dbscan_try/dbscan.cpp ) 
set(project_HEADERS 
   /home/raman/Work/cplusplus_projects/dbscan_try/dbscan.h) 
set(OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS "${OpenCV_INSTALL_PATH}/include/opencv;${OpenCV_INSTALL_PATH}/include")

find_package(OpenCV 3.1.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS) include_directories(-L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_saliency -lboost_system -lopencv_contrib) set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -Wall")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${project_SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(dbscan_try ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

However, I am getting errors such as:

```
/home/raman/Work/cplusplus_projects/dbscan_try/dbscan.cpp:88: error: undefined reference to omp_set_num_threads'
/home/raman/Work/cplusplus_projects/dbscan_try/dbscan.cpp:89: error: undefined reference toGOMP_parallel_start'
etc.
```

I am new to C++ and cmake so I am not sure if I am doing somethign wrong here. I seem to have followed what other suggestions here mentioned and it worked for them.

Comment: Current code (even before editing by @Jonny Henly) has broken lines terminators (CMake doesn't allow several commands on the same line). Please, [edit] you post with correct code. For achive proper code formatting, use `Ctrl+K` keys combination (while code is selected).

Comment: I have edited my code. I got it to work by adding    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -fopenmp")         at the end of set commands. I am not sure why that worked though.

Comment: Compiler flag `-fopenmp` should be detected with `find_package(OpenMP)` call and be set via `OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS` variable. What is content of this variable in your case? Probably, find script is confused by command `add_definitions("-lgomp")`: normally, all `-l` flags should be set for linker (`CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`  variable or `target_link_libraries()` command).